# fail2ban BANTIME not working for SASL

Tags: fail2ban

My fail2ban bantime does not appear to be working. I still get repeated ban notifications from the same IP within 45 minutes of each other. My bantime is set to 24 hours.

```
[sasl]
enabled  = true
port     = smtp
filter   = sasl
action = iptables-multiport[name=sasl, port="smtp,ssmtp", protocol=tcp]
    sendmail-whois-lines[name=SASL, dest=xxx@gmail.com,sender=fail2ban@xxx.com, logpath=/var/log/mail.log]
    complain[logpath=/var/log/mail.log]
logpath  = /var/log/mail.log
maxretry = 3
findtime = 10800 # 3 hours
bantime  = 86400 # 24h
```

This is in /etc/fail2ban/jail.local

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Discovered fail2ban does not like in-line comments.

changed to:

```
# 3 hours
findtime = 10800
# 24 hrs
bantime  = 86400
```

and it all began to work correctly.